# Gridview Get Cells ID

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to select `gridview` to get the ID. My code is below. What can I do to achieve this?

```
 protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     int id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].ToString());
     TextBox2.Text = id.ToString();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this , it may work for u ,Call cell id directly.

```
 this.GridView1.CellClick += new System.Windows.Forms.GridViewCellEventHandler(this.GridView1_CellClick);
private void GridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    string id = GridView1.Rows[GridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells["ID"].Value.ToString();
    textBox1.Text = id;
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
  }
}
```

or change this in ur code..

```
string id = GridView1.Rows[GridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
  textBox1.Text = id;
```

Add this...

```
  <asp:TemplateField> 
  <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:CheckBox ID="chksec" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" oncheckedchanged="chksec_CheckedChanged1" />
  </ItemTemplate> 
  </asp:TemplateField>


 protected void chksec_CheckedChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Checkbox is checked");
}
```

Comment: protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int id = int.Parse(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0]);
           
up code error code. int.Parse(string) has some invalid arguments.

            TextBox2.Text = id.ToString();

        }

Comment: string id = GridView1.Rows[GridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            textBox1.Text = id;  Like this I have error. CurrentRow not definition on Gridview

Comment: did u check selectedrow instead of cuurrentrow ?

Comment: string silinecekler = "";
            foreach (GridViewRow satirbilgi in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)satirbilgi.FindControl("chcksec");
                if (chk.Checked)
                {
                    silinecekler += satirbilgi.Cells[3].Text;
                    TextBox1.Text = silinecekler;
                    
                }
I want click the checkbox and delete this row.How can I do. This code chk.Checked not working.

Comment: foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
                {
                    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkApproved");
                     if (chk != null && chk.Checked)
                    {
                        Response.Write("Checkbox is checked");
                    }                                  
                }

Comment: u code works fine, but why did u use  += there, are u storing more than one value in silinecekler ?

Comment: foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chksec");
                if (chk != null && chk.Checked)
                {

                    Response.Write("Seçildi");

                }


            }

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chksec" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSec" runat="server" Text="Sil" OnClick="btnSec_Click" /> My grid view code. Still not working. Why ? I am angry.

Comment: hey check this , i have added a code below add this, check my edit

Comment: <asp:TemplateField> 
  <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:CheckBox ID="chksec" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" oncheckedchanged="chksec_CheckedChanged1" />
  </ItemTemplate> 
  </asp:TemplateField>


 protected void chksec_CheckedChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Checkbox is checked");
}

Comment: Thank you very much. sorry my fault. I forgot !IsPostback :((.

Comment: Can I Help me. Do you know asp.net, entity framework with procedure. Do you have example. I

Comment: using (KurumsalDataContext krm = new KurumsalDataContext())
            {
                Kategoriler kat = new Kategoriler
                {
                    KategoriAd = TextBox1.Text


                };

                krm.Kategorilers.InsertOnSubmit(kat);
                krm.SubmitChanges();
            }

            Get();

Comment: My code up with procedure. But I have admin file in project. This fils will be admin panel. This code not working in admin file. Why :((. How can I do entitiy with framework etc.